# Where should I post question about authenticating users?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about authenticating users, specifically validating that an individual is an employee at one of a large number of companies (probably using their company's email address, which I don't know before hand). Based on my prelim research there seems to be the most overlap with IT security exchange.

Comment: Using a federated service? SAML? Or asking which technologies you should use, or the security risks? Sounds like you could easily have a couple of questions that span multiple sites.

Comment: For a website. The idea being some users are the general public and others are from these companies. And I need some way to authenticate that the users claiming to be employees are being honest without being draconian and having a friendly enough UI.

Comment: What if you just did the usual email verification thing, and then checked the domain name of the email address against your known list of companies?  The closest site to ask your question is probably http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RobertHarvey well I did an informal survey of people I know and the domains and emails might not always match exactly so you might have a company with a website foo.com and an email billy@foobar.com (although foobar.com did redirect back to foo.com). And while I can easily check that I'm not sure what other variations might be out there (maybe fooLA.com and email billy@foolosangeles.com) It's definitely a starting point but someone might have a more complete solution.